# R Error: Couldn't resolve host name

Tags: r, curl, host

I'm fairly new to R and was given the task of validating data using R script provided by a 3rd party. In order to access the validation package created by the third party, I was instructed to create a json file with the baseurl, username, and password to access the site.

Then I tried to load the package, and load the json file and received an "Error in curl... Couldn't resolve host name"

I'm not quite sure what to do now, any help would be appreciated. The relevant code is below:

JSON file: (baseurl is just placeholder)

```
{
  "dhis": {
   "baseurl": "http://de.data.org",
   "username": "admin",
  "password": "district"
  }
}
```

Loading the package/providing location code in R:

```
>require(datimvalidation)
>secrets<-"C:/Users/Owner/Secrets/data.json"
>loadSecrets(secrets)
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Couldn't resolve host name
```

Comment: I had this issue when i was behind a proxy. So i just added the proxy configurations:  set_config(use_proxy(url="127.0.0.1",port=0000)) and it was fine. (Found the answer on stackoverflow, but i have closed the link)